# Cocoa library to interact with any web service API

Tags: web-services, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there a general Cocoa or Cocoa Touch library for interacting with any web service API, or one which can be used as a basis for creating my own library for a web service? For example, I could add some details about how to interact with the [Vimeo API](http://vimeo.com/api) (how to verify user details, what URLs to call). I'm not sure how this would work in reality.

If not, can anyone suggest an web service library which I could alter to change the API calls? It would need to be fairly simple (a small API) and easy to adapt. An example is this [Cocoa library for Twitter](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) (although it would probably be too complicated to adapt). Would it be easier just to code it up from scratch?

Comment: Your question is confusing, which I think may stem from a misunderstanding of what **API** means. You seem to be referring to it in terms of web services, whereas API means **Application Programming Interface** and refers to any set of rules that you use to communicate with a piece of software. For example, Cocoa is a framework that contains many different APIs. Your need to "interact with any API" makes no sense in this context. You need to reframe your question to talk about web services specifically.

Comment: Yes, the library is `libobjc.dylib`.  It holds the implementation of the Objective-C runtime and is required to interact with any API in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. I think that "API" is used very widely around the web to mean a web service: People talk about the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api) or the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/start). I'll edit the question to make it clearer what kind I mean.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: sorry, I wasn't talking about the Cocoa API, but something like the Twitter API.

Comment: @nevan The term **API** is used very widely in *programming*. It is a generic term and is absolutely not just used in relation to web services. The web services you mention vend APIs, but that just means they allow programmers to interact with their service, just as Cocoa allows you to interact with its services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a library that will automagically work with any web API. In fact I don't even think it's possible to write such a library, since you can define your web API any way you want to. That library would have to be pretty smart in order to figure out how to use an arbitrary API.

I think the closest you'll get is something like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is a great library for interacting with web services. If you add a JSON and/or XML parser you'll have everything you need to interact with almost any web API.

Answer (score 0):

Found another library for interacting with RESTful web services. It's called [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). From their description:

> RestKit is a Cocoa framework for interacting with RESTful web services in Objective C on iOS and Mac OS X. It provides a set of primitives for interacting with web services wrapping GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP verbs behind a clean, simple interface. RestKit also provides a system for modeling remote resources by mapping them from JSON (or XML) payloads back into local domain objects. Object mapping functions with normal NSObject derived classes with properties. There is also an object mapping implementation included that provides a Core Data backed store for persisting objects loaded from the web.